# Redirect requests

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite

Im using that rule

```
^(?!webmaster)[\w\/\d\_\-\:\;\?\=\.]+$
```

to match all request which are different of webmaster. 
How to match request which are different of webmaster **OR** some_other_dir ?

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
^(?!(?:webmaster|SomeOtherDir))[\w\/\d\_\-\:\;\?\=\.]+$
```

The `(?:webmaster|SomeOtherDir)` is a non capturing group and the `|` is a "OR"

You can also simplify your character group, within a character group most characters don't need to be escaped, the `-` has to be at the beginning or the end (or needs escaping) otherwise it defines a character range, so I moved it to the end. The `_` is included in `\w` so does not need to be listed. (I am not sure about the `/`, so I leave it as it is)

```
^(?!(?:webmaster|SomeOtherDir))[\w\/\d:;?=.-]+$
```